# Assigning the correct URL for your controller

Tags: url, controllers, ajax

So i'm developing an ajax application in which a controller intakes and outputs information for a user.  What is the standard way to figure out the URL for the controller?  I'm unsure of the best route to take.

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is using `:module/:controller/:action/*` routing scheme which was inherited from Zend Framework.

Assuming you are working with front controller and have following definition in your config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <yourmodule>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Example_Yourmodule</module>
                <frontName>yourmodule</frontName>
            </args>
        </yourmodule>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Also assuming you have your controller in `app/code/local/Example/Yourmodule/controllers/AjaxController.php`

```
class Example_Yourmodule_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
     // do something
    }
}
```

Your path would be `yourmodule/ajax/index`. To get the URL you can call `Mage::getUrl('yourmodule/ajax/index');`